# How can I do: required="false" in grails g:select?

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

required="false" does not work in "g:select" tag

---

Example:

```
<g:select from="${}" name="select" required="false" />
```

and

```
<g:select from="${}" name="select" required="true" />
```

produces a html tag **required** (in html5)

---

How can I make the "g:select" produces the required or not, **dynamically**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove required, for eg:

```
<g:select id="select" from="${}" name="select"/>
```

You can use jquery to change the g:select to be required or not required. For example, lets say you have another

```
<g:select id="yesNo" from="[yes, no]">
```

In the gsp, use javascript:

```
$( "#yesNo" ).change(function() {
  if($(this)[0].value == "yes") {
     $( "#select" ).attr('required', 'required')
  }
  else {
     $( "#select" ).removeProp( "required" )
  }
});
```

---

Another approach is if you pass a variable `required` to gsp, you can use `<g:if>`:

In controller:

```
[required: "true"] //If dont want required, simply don't return required at all
```

In gsp:

```
<g:if test="${required}">
   <g:select from="${}" name="select" required/>
</g:if>
<g:else>
   <g:select from="${}" name="select"/>
</g:else>
```

Comment: This is not dynamic

Comment: How do you want to trigger it to be required or not? What I can think of is using jquery, check my edited answer

Comment: Yes, I have to use the "g:if" solution, repeating the "g:select" twice. There seems to be no better solution for now.

Comment: why not use javacript? if ${required}, then $( "#select" ).attr('required', 'required')

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:select from="${}" name="select" required="${false/true}" />
```

should work !